# Excel Formula LOOKUP, how does this works?

Tags: excel-formula

In an excel sheet, I have 10 cells in row 1 (A1:J1) with rather random values, say, as below:

```
-----------------------------------------
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 6 | 8 | 2 | 9 |   | 6 | 2 | 4 |   |   |
-----------------------------------------
```

Note that there are also some blank cells.
Then in another cell, I set up the formula:

```
=LOOKUP(100,A1:J1)
```

Then it **always** successfully acquires *the value of the last non-empty cell*.
That's desired, but why? How does this happen?

I have read through the documentation for `LOOKUP` function, but still could not understand.
I also tried similar tricks on column range, and it works well, too.

I am sorry but I forget where I got this trick, it should be by googling, years ago.

Comment: Change H1 to 101 and see what happens :)

Comment: @BigBen Thanks. Sure, it will make difference. But I still cannot explain the behavior based on documented functionality of `LOOKUP`.

Comment: From the [docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb): With the HLOOKUP and VLOOKUP functions, you can index down or across, but LOOKUP always selects the last value in the row or column

Answer (score 0):

Excel `LOOKUP` works based on approximate match. More precisely, a Lookup formula searches for exact match first. If it cannot find the lookup value exactly, it looks up the next smallest value, i.e. the largest value in `lookup_vector` that is less than or equal to `lookup_value`.

Source: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/04/05/excel-lookup-function/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and reference link. However, the `next smallest value` near 100 should be the `9` in cell D1, not the `4` in the last non-blank cell.
Actually the lookup_vector is not sorted at all. I am just curious why it always works to get the value of last non-blank cell.

Comment: Yes it is a strange behavior but for it for work fine the array has to be sorted. Try searching for number `3`